# Wordpress ajax not passing variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Im trying to pass a variable from one php file to another using wordpress ajax and then reloading the php(part of a page) that received the variable so it can show the updated data. When using the following the ajax code returns 0 as the response

**jQuery that passes the data to the php file**

```
echo    '<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){

                    jQuery( ".facetwp-page" ).click(function() {
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            url:  "'.admin_url("admin-ajax.php").'",
                            data: { "action" : "query_for_map", "mydata" : "'.json_encode($this->query_args).'" },
                            success: function(response, d){
                                console.log(response);
                                jQuery(".page-head").load("'.get_template_directory_uri().'/banners/map_based_banner.php");
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });

                </script>';
```

**File that contains the php code that receives the data from jQuery**

```
function query_for_map() {

echo json_decode($_POST['mydata']);

}
add_action('wp_ajax_query_for_map', 'query_for_map');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_query_for_map', 'query_for_map');
```

Im only outputting the posted variable to see if it works but it doesnt. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: In the js console on the ajax call, are you able to see the value posted as a parameter? and what does mydata look like?

Comment: @tellez I see some data pertaining to a wordpress post. Like this {"post_type":"property","post_status":"publish","posts_per_page":12,"property-type":"building","paged":1,"post__in":["489813","480483","454036","454029","454020","454013","454006","453998","452908","451151","389738","389731","389723","389716","389710","389700","389693","389687","389681","389675","389668","389663","389657","389652","389645","389641","389635","389627","389620","389614","389606","379927","379914","379866","379862","379847","379821"]}" },